# Removing App from Recent Apps in android using adb shell command

Tags: android, adb

I want to remove an application from recent apps using shell command. please help me with a working solution.

Thanks
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove from the recent but you can kill your application using command line,

kill [options]     Kill all processes associated with  (the app's package name). This command kills only processes that are safe to kill and that will not impact the user experience.

Options are:
--user  | all | current: Specify user whose processes to kill; all users if not specified.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html for your reference.

I hope this will help you.